# App logo not showing on different devices

Tags: android, android-activity, icons

I have a samsung phone and a Motorolla phone. On my Samsung phone my propgrammed and set custom app icon is used and displayed. On my Motorolla this is not the case. Instead the default android logo remains. Any clue why this is?

Comment: Make sure you have added `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` in manifest file\

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps :

1) add app icon in ***mipmap folder*** with different sizes

2) In Menifest.xml  set  `android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"` and    `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"`

Answer (score 0):

^ Make sure you have added android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" in manifest file